# Can I shuffle a list to receive a specific pattern?

Tags: python, algorithm, design-patterns, shuffle

I am trying to make a fictional topographical map so i need a specific pattern for the shuffled list. i have already made the list and can shuffle it but i cannot seem to shuffle it to a specific pattern.
eg.

```
n = [1,4,2,3,5,4,3]
shuffle(n)
print(n)
[3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
shuffle(n)
print(n)
[4,5,4,3,3,2,1]
```

basically i need the shuffled list to only go up and down by 1 each time rather then a completely random list.

I tried to print out the list using a seed but that gives me the same list everytime what i need is to sort it into the specific order

Comment: That's not a shuffle.  It's a semi-ordered list.  You're going to have to write code to semi-order your list.

Comment: Is [4,5,4,3,3,2,1] a valid output?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that such a permutation exists? Assuming at least one does, do you just need to find one or to find them all, or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "go up and down by one?"  Are you talking rotations, where `[1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3]` could go to `[4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1]` or `[3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4]` or about fixed dec/increments of elements, so that `[1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3]` could go to `[2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4]` or `[0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3]`, or random dec/increments, so that `[1,4,2,3,5,4,3]` could go, for instance to `[1+1, 4+1, 2-1, 3+1, 5-1, 4-1, 3-1]`, which is `[2, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2]` or something else entirely?

Comment: @Scott Sauyet  as in add one or subtract one or stay the same as in [4,2,5,3,2,4,3] becomes [2,3,4,5,4,3,2]so they all come at increments of one.

Comment: @Dave - Yes this permutation exsists but it's the finding it that is the problem if there is a way to calculate a possible seed that would work i just don't know it. and finding them all should just be a part of finding that seed

Comment: @user3386109 - yes [4,5,4,3,3,2,1] is a valid output

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - how would recomend i do that? like if i had [3,5,4] i would go random.shuffle(list) and make three if statments and put the whole thing in a while loop?

Comment: You can just sort the list to get a valid output. And then you can rearrange the duplicates. For example if the sorted list is `1,2,3,3,4,4,5`, you've got an extra 3 and an extra 4 that can be moved. Moving a 4 gives `1,2,3,3,4,5,4`. Moving a 3 gives `1,2,3,4,3,4,5`. Moving 3 and 4 gives `1,2,3,4,5,4,3`. And of course, you can reverse any of those lists to get four more solutions.

Comment: One way is to pick the first value at random.  Then the next value must either go up or down by zero or one.  If you can use all the values, you're done.  If not, pick a different first value at random and repeat the process.  Very inefficient, but for small values of N, like 7, doable.

Comment: Can you explain how these are generated so that you know such a permutation is possible?  Obviously `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]` could not possibly work.  So where do they come from that  you have such a guarantee?

Comment: Also, how long are you lists?  Would it be acceptable to simply filter the list of all permutations of you original list to find those that meet your criteria and then randomly select one of them?

Comment: The simplest way to generate a list that's guaranteed to have a solution is to pick a random starting value, and a random length. Begin with a list of length 1 that contains the starting value. While the list length is less than the desired length, append an element that is either equal to or 1 greater than the last element in the list. You can then shuffle the array if you want to make the problem look harder than it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technique which will only work if your input is relatively short, as it calculates all permutations of the original, filters them to include only those with such small steps, then returns a function which will randomly generate one of them.  If the array length is large, this will take far too long.

This is a JavaScript implementation, but it should be easy enough to translate into any modern language:

```js
const smallInc = (ns) =>  Object .keys (ns) .slice (1) .every (
  i => Math .abs (ns [i] - ns [i - 1]) <= 1
)

const rotations = ([l, ...ls], rs = []) => 
  l == undefined ? [] : [[l, ...ls, ...rs], ... rotations (ls, [...rs, l])]

const permutations = ([l, ...ls]) =>
  l == undefined ? [[]] : [...permutations (ls) .flatMap (p => rotations ([l, ...p])) ]

const randomizer = (ns, xs = permutations (ns) .filter (smallInc)) =>
  xs .length > 0
    ? () => xs [~~ (Math .random () * xs .length) ]
    : () => ns // throw error?  Something else?

const perms = randomizer ([1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3])

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i ++) console .log (`[${perms ()}]`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I choose here to return the original if there are no possible matching permutations.  I don't know if you'd prefer to throw an error or do something else in that case.  You say that such will always be possible, but I'd be very curious to see how you're generating these so that you know that.  (Obviously that is possible.  The original could be a shuffled version of an array built value-by-value with some initial value and subsequent ones just being increment, decrement, or identity transformations of their successors.  But I'd be curious to see why this randomization is needed if you are already creating them this way.)

If you only ever need one, we can simplify `randomize` to return a random value rather than return a function that will continually do that.  The current design is an optimization that may not be necessary. It caches the permutation calculation and the filtering.

You might wonder about duplicates.  In fact, in this case, there are 32 permutations that match, each of eight distinct permutations has four duplicates (2! * 2!, because there are two copies of `3` and two of `4` in the original), so our randomization will work the same without first applying uniqueness.  The same will be true for any input.

But again, this will only work if your input is small enough to let us quickly calculate all (`n!`) permutations.

Comment: what coding language is this in?

Comment: @DNA-41:  Sorry, this is JavaScript.  I'll edit the post to make that clear.

Comment: Because i need it in Python

Comment: You might want to [edit] the post to add the "python" tag, then.  Generally, if there are algorithm questions with no language listed, it's assumed that most any language will do.